# Replace content in between tags for data from another php file

Tags: php

Ok whole case, updated, I have some code saved and encoded in the database like this:

```
W1BIUF0KW1ZJRVdJRF0xWy9WSUVXSURdCjw/ICRjb25uID0gbmV3IFBETyggREJfRFNOLCBEQl9VU0VSTkFNRSwgREJfUEFTU1dPUkQgKTsgJHNxbCA9ICJzZWxlY3QgKiBmcm9tIHV6aXZhdGVsZSI7JHN0ID0gJGNvbm4tPnByZXBhcmUoICRzcWwgKTskc3QtPmV4ZWN1dGUoKTskY29ubiA9IG51bGw7IGZvcmVhY2ggKCAkc3QgYXMgJHN0cmVzdWx0ICkgeyA/Pgo8PyBlY2hvICRzdHJlc3VsdFsiaWQiXTs/Pgo8PyB9ID8+ClsvUEhQXQoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgo=
```

decoded result is this:

```
[PHP]
[VIEWID]1[/VIEWID]
<? $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); $sql = "select * from uzivatele";$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );$st->execute();$conn = null; foreach ( $st as $stresult ) { ?>
<? echo $stresult["id"];?>
<? } ?>
[/PHP]
```

Then I have root file where I download all template parts that are encoded like I stated, I decode them, take the code inside [PHP][/PHP] and create a seperate phpview file that generates some content  and that content I need to be swapped for the previous code that was inside  [PHP][/PHP]. Of course If I generate from that php file another html file I can use file_get_contents, but  I would like to find approach with just the one php file

```
<?
if ( !defined( 'DB_DSN' ) ) {require( "./../../pripojeni.php" );}
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );


function get_string_between( $string, $start, $end ) {
  $string = ' ' . $string;
  $ini = strpos( $string, $start );
  if ( $ini == 0 ) return '';
  $ini += strlen( $start );
  $len = strpos( $string, $end, $ini ) - $ini;
  return substr( $string, $ini, $len );
}

function replace_between($str, $needle_start, $needle_end, $replacement) {
    $pos = strpos($str, $needle_start);
    $start = $pos === false ? 0 : $pos + strlen($needle_start);

    $pos = strpos($str, $needle_end, $start);
    $end = $pos === false ? strlen($str) : $pos;

    return substr_replace($str, $replacement, $start, $end - $start);
}

$aktivniverzeproaktivniobsah = $_GET[ "id" ];
$sqlaktivniobsah = "select tp.* from template tp left join sekce sk on sk.template=tp.id left join verze vz on vz.id=sk.kverzi where vz.id=$aktivniverzeproaktivniobsah order by sk.poradi ASC";
$staktivniobsah = $conn->prepare( $sqlaktivniobsah );
$staktivniobsah->execute();
$conn = null;
$contentdecoded="";

foreach ( $staktivniobsah as $aktivniobsah ) {
  $idcko = $aktivniobsah[ 'id' ];
  $contentdecoded .= base64_decode( $aktivniobsah[ "obsah" ] );
}

if ( str_contains( $contentdecoded, '[PHP]' ) ) {
  $str = get_string_between( $contentdecoded, '[PHP]', '[/PHP]' );
  $idview = get_string_between( $contentdecoded, '[VIEWID]', '[/VIEWID]' );
  if ( !empty( $idview )and!empty( $str ) ) {
    $fp = fopen( 'wms/admin/views/view' . $idview . '.php', 'w' );
    fwrite( $fp, $str );
    fclose( $fp );
  }
 $dokument=file_get_contents( 'wms/admin/views/view' . $idview . '.php' );
 $contentdecoded=replace_between($contentdecoded, '[PHP]', '[/PHP]', $dokument  );
}

echo $contentdecoded;
?>
```

Comment: Why not move that `require` call down to where the output **should** be shown?

Comment: _Which_ require statement are you talking about here? `require( "./../../pripojeni.php" );` in script "A" - so that would mean `./../../pripojeni.php` is actually script "B" then? Why is your "A" script looping over that selected data and outputting the ID of each record in the first place, what is the purpose of that?

Comment: Please be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: @NicoHaase I will of course use another encoding with custom vars

Comment: Please don't add answers to your question. Use the answer section for this. Also, prepared statements are not any kind of "encoding with custom vars"

Comment: `$sqlaktivniobsah = "select tp.* from template tp left join sekce sk on sk.template=tp.id left join verze vz on vz.id=sk.kverzi where vz.id= :id order by sk.poradi ASC";
$staktivniobsah = $conn->prepare( $sqlaktivniobsah );
$staktivniobsah->execute([ "id" => $aktivniverzeproaktivniobsah]);` is how your query should be written. The key thing is to use prepared statements **with parameters** to properly protect your data, See also [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either change `view$idview.php` to be a function which returns a string or you can use [Output Buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to capture the output and render it where needed. What `require` does is that it loads and executes (if any executable code is present) the file, therefore the things appear above the replace. Also note that [`require` doesn't seem](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) to have any output value, so storing it into a `$document` variable will assign probably nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will investigate this ruther.

Answer (score -3):

Use file_get_contents instead of require to get the contents of a file.

Comment: File get contents return the content of the file, but not exeuted.

Comment: This completely changes the logic of the script. Can you share how this would resolve the problem?